# How to detect installed version of MS Office using javascript from IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ms-office, office-2013

Actually I need to know if 2013 version of MS Office installed.
Approach with

```
var oApplication=new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
```

does not work for me from website (but it works when run it from local disk).

Comment: I would hope that you can't do this - as a user I don't want the websites I visit to be able to detect what software I have installed. This sort of thing is reasonably acceptable in a controlled environment like a company intranet, but then in such an environment you'd presumably already know what version of Office was installed...

Comment: I need to open MS Office documents for editing from my website in internet. But old mechanism for doing this was broken with MS Office 2013. So I have to know which way to use - old one for Office 2010 or new one - for Office 2013. And I don't care if someone tracks what I'm doing and what programs I have. Because nobody needs me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so here is the answer (SharePoint works properly with both old and new Office clients without version detection, so there must be a solution)

```
try {
    var g = new ActiveXObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.5");
    alert('Office 2013 installed');
    window.open('ms-word:ofe|u|http://server.com/12.docx');
}
catch (h) {
    alert('Office 2010/older installed');
    var g = new ActiveXObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments");
    g.EditDocument('http://server.com/12.docx');
}
```

The only problem left is document opening in 'Protected View' while SharePoint opens them in regular view.

Comment: thanks, that helps me;
I debugged Office365:<br>
ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|https://....  => Powerpoint<br>
ms-word:ofe|u|https://            => Word<br>
ms-excel:ofe|u|https://           => Excel

Answer (score 2):

I debugged in Office365:
ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|https://....  => Powerpoint
ms-word:ofe|u|https://            => Word
ms-excel:ofe|u|https://           => Excel

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate ActiveX controls which aren't marked "Safe for Scripting" from the Internet Zone in IE (and the Office apps aren't SFS).

What "old mechanism" were you using prior to Office 2013 and what "new mechanism" are you planning to use?

(Keep in mind that SharePoint works properly with both old and new Office clients without version detection).

Comment: I've answered your question in my own answer here.